# Создание сервера на Node JS, привязал html страницы, как привязать стили и js код?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

Учусь работать с nodeJS и хочу загрузить на сервер сайт в несколько страниц. Есть 2 html документа, подключение к ним рабочее, но не понимаю как подключить файлы JS и CSS. Знаю что отправляю только html, просто не знаю как отправить остальное.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs"); // модуль файловой системы
const path = require("path"); // помощь в формировании корректного пути

const PORT = 3000;

const createPath = (page) => path.resolve(__dirname, "./site/html_css", `${page}.html`);

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("Server request");

let basePath = "";

switch(req.url) {
    case '/':
        basePath = createPath('main');
        break;
    case '/register.html':
        basePath = createPath("register");
        break;
    default:
        res.statusCode = 404;
}

fs.readFile(basePath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.end(data);
    }
})
});
```

Comment: `не знаю как отправить остальное` все так же и отправляй... Получаешь запрос на файл... Определяешь путь до файла на сервере... Читаешь его и отправляешь.